# Input a message inside a box

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to create a box with parameters that prints any input the user puts in. I figured that the box should be the length of the string, but I'm stuck with empty code, because I don't know where to start.

It should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I agree with [Daniel Goldfarb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1639359/daniel-goldfarb) comments. Don't look for help without trying.

If you still couldn't get how to do that, then only read my remaining comment.

Just print : 
str = string entered
len(str) = string length

```
+-(len(str) * '-')-+    
|        str       |
+-(len(str) * '-')-+
```

Answer (score 0):

So hopefully you can learn, don't want to just write the code for you.  Basically break it into steps.  First you need to accept user input.  If you don't know how to do that, try googling, "python accept user input from stdin" or here is one of the results from that search: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/getting-user-input-from-the-keyboard

Then, as you mentioned, you need the length of the string that was input.  You can get that with the len function.  Then do the math:  It looks like you want "|" and two spaces on each side of the string, giving the length plus 6 ("|  " on either side).  This new length is what you should make the "+---+" strings.  Use the print() function to print out each line.  I really don't want to say much more than that because you should exercise your brain to figure it out.  If you have a question on how to generate "+---+" of the appropriate length (appropriate number of "-" characters) you can use string concatenation and a loop, or just use the python string constructor (hint: google "construct python string of len repeat characters").  HTH.

One more thing, after looking at your code, in addition to my comment about printing the string itself within the box, I see some *minor* logic errors in your code (for example, why are you *subtracting* 2 from the width).  THE POINT i want to me here is, if you ware going to break this into multiple small functions (a bit overkill here, but definitely a good idea if you are just learning as it teaches you an important skill) then YOU SHOULD TEST EACH FUNCTION individually to make sure it does what you think and expect it to do.  I think you will see your logic errors that way.

Comment: I created this box before and thought I could edit it a little bit, but it uses paramaters width & height. The box I have to create right now only allows paramater (s) https://pastebin.com/h54nvYcf

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying here "I created this box before and thought I could edit it a little bit, but it uses parameters width & height."  Maybe you need to accept the string to output also as a parameter?  Certainly you need to print that string along with the sides of the box.  (You can't just print the box and expect the string to print itself);  again I'm not sure exactly what you are asking ... looks like you are on the right track though.

Comment: Thank you for your help on the input and len function. I came up with this code:https://pastebin.com/97bMeM7T The only issue right now is that the paramater (s) isn't used. I don't know what it should be used for.

Comment: You are definitely on the right track.  Play with the code, make small changes and see what happens, test individual functions; once you are on the right track, the best way to learn is to learn by doing.  I think you will get it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, but I recommend to try it out by yourself, breakdown the problem into smaller pieces and start from there.

```
def format(word):
    #It declares all the necessary variables
    borders =[]
    result = []

    # First part of the result--> it gives the two spaces and the "wall"
    result.append("|  ")
   # Second part of the result (the word)
    for letter in word:
    result.append(letter)
    # Third part of the result--> Ends the format
    result.append("  |")
    #Transforms the list to a string
    result = "".join(result)

    borders.append("+")
    borders.append("--"+"-"*len(word)+"--")
    borders.append("+")
    borders="".join(borders)
    print(borders)
    print(result)
    print(borders)


sentence = input("Enter a word: ")
format(sentence)
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm new to Python, and I've found this solution. Maybe is not the best solution, but it works!

```
test = input()

print("+-", end='')
for i in test:
    print("-", end='')
print("-+")
print("| " + test + " |")
print("+-", end='')
for i in test:
    print("-", end='') 
print("-+")
```

Comment: I wrote this: https://pastebin.com/n5zQcath only thing left is to figure out how to implement the paramater (s). I'm still not sure what it is doing in the function.

Comment: Great that you came up with something (although not very elegant).  But for simple questions like this, please don't just give the answer: that doesn't help anyone learn how to learn.

Comment: @Krofighter I can't understand what your (s) parameter will do. I that way it will do anything. Please modify your question if is incomplete